# Video scaled with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, video

I have a serious problem with Internet explorer.
I really need to use the scale function in my CSS, but the quality of the video is totally deteriorated.
It works fine with Chrome (and Firefox i think) but not with IE.

Are there any tips to make this better ?
I saw some css tips to change the quality of images but this doesn't work with videos.

Here is a code test (put the cursor over the video to scale it): http://jsfiddle.net/MxxAv/145/

**HTML:**

```
<video autoplay id="video" src="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4" poster="http://thumb.multicastmedia.com/thumbs/aid/w/h/t1351705158/1571585.jpg"></video>
```

**CSS**

```
#video {
    width: 200px;
    height: 113px;
}

#video:hover {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: scale(2.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.3);
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: try adding `-moz` as well.

Comment: try using javascript to load the image in large scale then afterwards you can resize it. never tried it but thought it might be helpful. furthermore i wouldn't recommend css3 because it is not supported by old browsers anyway.

Comment: Any exemple please ? (I'm not using jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an original scale may help. Also, for cross-browser support, it helps to use all of the vendor prefixes. Notice, I moved the commands with no prefix to the bottom. Browsers apply the last usable command, so if a browser needs the prefix, you can simply move the prefixed command to the bottom. I added the vendor prefixes and scale to your code, and a duration just for kicks :)

```
#video {
    width: 284px;
    height: 160px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#video:hover {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(2.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(2.8);
    -o-transform: scale(2.8);
    transform: scale(2.8);
}
```

Comment: Nothing change, the quality is still bad (pixelated) in Internet Explorer.
My sample have not all prefixes because the bug exist only on IE, so it's just for exemple.

Comment: I had the same experience with scaling images... what about setting height & width dimensions for normal state and hover? There may be something similar to `img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }` for videos:/

Comment: P.S. An IE update fixed my image scaling problem. Hopefully they will address video scaling in the near future?! Unfortunately, as you may already know, `-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;` and `-ms-interpolation-mode: neareast-neighbor;` only work for IE 7 & 8. It baffles me why updated versions fix some problems, while (re)introducing others. My `3dtransforms` worked beautifully on all browsers but IE until recently, but now only Chrome & Safari.